# How to set .htaccess for 2 type get value on the same page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For this page `test.php`

i have to use 2 format url

```
www.example.com/test/1234
```

and

```
www.example.com/test/1234/abcd
```

My `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ /test.php?one=$1&two=$2 [L]
```

It's work good with `www.example.com/test/1234/abcd` but redirect internal error with `www.example.com/test/1234`

I want to know how can i edit `.htaccess` for work good with my 2 url format on `test.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^-]*)$ /test.php?one=$1&two=$2 [L]
```

Just remove the 2nd `/([^-]*)` it is making no difference, as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/9xszQS/1). Removing it will allow for you to access `www.example.com/test/1234` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^/-]+)(?:/([^-]*))?$ /test.php?one=$1&two=$2 [L]
```